# How to get the selected value of a dropdowlist with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a table with several `@Html.dropdowlistfor` in it.

I was trying to read the selected value byusing javascript, but all read is the html generated.
How can I read it??

```
for (var i = 0; i < oTable.length; i++) {
  **userModel.Id    = oTable[i][0];**

  regionModel.Users.push(userModel);
  processModel.Regions.push(regionModel);

  userModel   = { "Id": "", "Name": ""};
  regionModel = { "Id": "", "Name": "", "Users": []};
}
```

TABLE

```
<table class="tbl" id="tbl">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Region
                </th>
                <th>
                    Owner
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @if (Model != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in Model.Regions)
                {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayTextFor(i => item.Name)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(i => item.Users, new SelectList(item.Users, "Id", "Name"))
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
            }
        </tbody>
```

CODE

```
function ProcessSave() {
    // Step 1: Read View Data and Create JSON Object

    var userModel = { "User": "", "Name": ""};

    var regionModel = {"Region" : "","Name": "", "Users": []};

    var processModel = { "User": "", "Description": "", "Code": "", "Regions": []};

    var oTable = $('.tbl').dataTable().fnGetData();

        for (var i = 0; i < oTable.length; i++) {

            regionModel.Name  = oTable[i][0];

            userModel.User    = oTable[i][1];
            userModel.Name    = oTable[i][1];

            regionModel.Users.push(userModel);
            processModel.Regions.push(regionModel);

            userModel   = { "Id": "", "Name": ""};
            regionModel = { "Name": "", "Users": []};
       }
    // Step 1: Ends Here

    // Set 2: Ajax Post
    // Here i have used ajax post for saving/updating information
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Process/Create',
        data: JSON.stringify(processModel),
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json;',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {

            if (result.Success == "1") {
                window.location.href = "/Process/Index";
            }
            else {
                alert(result.ex);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

MODELS

```
 namespace TestingTool.ViewModels
    {
        public partial class ProcessModel
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public string Code { get; set; }

            public virtual ICollection<RegionModel> Regions { get; set; }
        }
    }

    namespace TestingTool.ViewModels
    {
        public class RegionModel
        {
            public int Region { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<UserModel> Users { get; set; }

        }
    }

    namespace TestingTool.ViewModels
    {
        public class UserModel
        {
            public int User{ get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

HTML OUTPUT

```
<table class="tbl" id="tbl">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Region
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Owner
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Belgium
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select id="item_Users" name="item.Users"><option value="1">Steven Segers</option>
<option value="2">Rui Martins</option>
</select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            France
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select id="item_Users" name="item.Users"><option value="1">Steven Segers</option>
<option value="2">Rui Martins</option>
</select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: Do you mean "with javascript"? `json` is more like a format for communicating data to/from a server and makes no sense in this context!

Comment: Json, js, whatever, I'm not very familiar with it, my thing is c#. If I have one dropdownlist, I know how to read from it. My problem is reading this one inside the table.

Comment: What is `oTable`, what is `userModel` and `regionModel`? What does the HTML look like that is output by your C# code? There's nowhere near enough detail to answer your question here im afraid (which is why you've not gotten an answer yet!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
$("#item_Users option:selected").index();
```

If you have many selects with same id try this (that selector select all 'select' with name attribute ending with Users :

```
 $("select[name$='Users']:eq(0) option:selected").index();  //get first select

 $("select[name$='Users']:eq(1) option:selected").index();  //get second select
```

But bad practices of usage multiple same id on page. Same id should single on page. But even you have multiple id on page would be better specify same class for all selects, in that case code will be shortly:

```
 $("select.Users:eq(0) option:selected").index();  //get first select

 $("select.Users:eq(1) option:selected").index();  //get second select
```

UPDATE:

```
$("select.Users").each(function (index, element) {
    var optionIndex = $(element).find("option:selected").index();
});
```

Comment: I think that would work if I had one dropdowlist, i have several with that id. But I did try it, still get 0.

Comment: This actually works. Instead of 0 and 1, how can I use a loop variable, $("select.Users:eq(i) option:selected").index(); ??

Comment: I managed to get it to work. But It returns the index of the selected item. How can I get the actual value of the selected item? In this case, 1, 2, 2010 and 2011                                                                      <select id="item_Users" name="item.Users">                        <option value="1">Steven Segers</option>
<option value="2">Rui Martins</option>
<option value="2010">Mohammed Chbabi</option>
<option value="2011">Peter Cortens</option>
</select>

Comment: `var selectedOptionValue = $(element).find("option:selected").val();`